# Error with API Key 401 error in .env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having an issue with attaching an API key from my .env file. The key works if its placed in the component. However if I import it from the .env file it doesnt work. Getting a 401 (Unauthorized). Used the Create React App. Tried many different ways to try to make it work (add const, add REACT_APP before the var..).

The .env file...

```js
REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY=`123456789123456789`;
```

The .jsx file...

```js
import React from "react";
import REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY from '../.env';

const REACT_APP_API_ADDRESS = REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY;

class WeatherInfo extends React.Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                items: [],
                isLoaded: false,
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Austin,USA&appid=${REACT_APP_API_ADDRESS}&units=imperial`)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should not load ENV files like this. There is a special node package which is pretty usefull for that, it does multiple things but the most important from them is that it really hides your .env and just inject the value into your process.env so that those values are not publicly accessible.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidance from here: [Node.js Everywhere with Environment Variables!](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786)